# Python: Mutability and dictionaries in config

Tags: python, json, dictionary, elasticsearch

I want to keep some large, static dictionaries in config to keep my main application code clean.  Another reason for doing that is so the dicts can be occasionally edited without having to touch the application.

I *thought* a good solution was using a json config a la:

http://www.ilovetux.com/Using-JSON-Configs-In-Python/

JSON is a natural, readable format for this type of data.  Example:

```
{
"search_dsl_full": {
  "function_score": {
    "boost_mode": "avg", 
    "functions": [
      {
        "filter": {
          "range": {
            "sort_priority_inverse": {
              "gte": 200
            }
          }
        }, 
        "weight": 2.4
      }
    ], 
    "query": {
      "multi_match": {
        "fields": [
          "name^10", 
          "search_words^5", 
          "description", 
          "skuid", 
          "backend_skuid"
        ], 
        "operator": "and", 
        "type": "cross_fields"
      }
    }, 
    "score_mode": "multiply"
  }
}
```

The big problem is, when I import it into my python app and set a dict equal to it like this:

```
with open("config.json", "r") as fin:
    config = json.load(fin)
...
def create_query()
    query_dsl = config['search_dsl_full']
    return query_dsl
```

and then later, only when a certain condition is met, I need to update that dict like this:

```
if (special condition is met):
    query_dsl['function_score']['query']['multi_match']['operator'] = 'or'
```

Since query_dsl is a reference, it updates the config dictionary too.  So when I call the function again, it reflects the updated-for-special-condition version ("or") rather than the the desired config default ("and").

I realize this is a newb issue (yes, I'm a python newb), but I can't seem to figure out a 'pythonic' solution.  I'm trying to not be a hack.

Possible options:

1. When I set query_dsl equal to the config dict, use copy.deepcopy()
2. Figure out how to make all nested slices of the config dictionary immutable
3. Maybe find a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?  I'm totally open to this whole approach being a preposterous newbie mistake.

Any help appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: When you "update the dict", what do you want the update to affect?  Like how broadly should that change propagate?  If you don't want the change to affect the config dict, why modify the dict at all?

Comment: I'd like the update to affect just the dict I made called query_dsl, and leave the original config dict alone.  I want the config dict to remain untouched, which is why I am not just using it directly later in the program (i'm updating the query_dsl dict).  Again, not against this whole idea being just newbie silliness.

Comment: Then it sounds like making a (deep) copy when you create `query_dsl` is the right solution.

Comment: That was my guess, but in searching for solutions to this it seemed to me that copying entire nested dicts was a not-oft-done scenario (which is what made me suspect my whole idea might be bunk).  Being a newb I'm trying my best to adhere to standard "pythonic" principles so I don't discover out down the road that my app was build on faulty logic.  But I guess that's all part of the process.  Thanks for your help.